# how to use session_start() with ajax?

Tags: php, ajax, session, load

basically, I have a dynamic php page that loads content using ajax. The content that it loads is supposed to get stuff from a session variable, but it can't because I don't have a `session_start()`. I do, its just that it's already processed when the actual page loads, and I can't add another `session_start()` when the content loads. Is there another way?

Thanks

Comment: `session_start()` just resumes the existing session if it's in progress, so you can call it in the AJAX handler.

Comment: As Barmar said, you can call session_start on all PHP script that are used for AJAX call. There is no restriction at this point.

Comment: You should most likely call `session_start` at the start of *every* request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

session_start() just resumes the existing session if it's in progress, so you can call it in the AJAX handler.